# unable to load image while creating a Pdf with HTML in swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pdf-generation

Please find my function below used for creating the pdf.
Pdf is creating but there is no image in it.

NOTE: i have a test.jpg image file already present in the documents folder.
Can anyone guide me where i am doing wrong.

```
    func createPDF() {
    var html = "<b>Hello <i>World!</i></b> <p>Generate PDF file from HTML in Swift</p><html><head><title><h2>Form Data</h2></title><style>table {font-family: arial, sans-serif;border-collapse: collapse;width: 100%;}td, th {border: 1px solid #dddddd;text-align: left;padding: 8px;}tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #dddddd;}</style></head><body><img src='test.jpg' alt='Red dot' /><table><tr><th>Company</th><th>Contact</th><th>Country</th></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td>This column is for testing the width and the wrapping of the text so that i can use this format for preparing the table for my project.</td><td>Maria Anders</td><td>Germany</td></tr><tr><td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td><td>Francisco Chang</td><td>Mexico</td></tr><tr><td>Ernst Handel</td><td>Roland Mendel</td><td>Austria</td></tr><tr><td></td><button type='button'>B1tton1</button><td></td></tr></table></body></html>"

    var myData: String = ""
    for i in 1...50
    {
      myData = myData + "Value is : \(i)"
    }

    html = html + myData

    let fmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: html)

    // 2. Assign print formatter to UIPrintPageRenderer

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(fmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    // 3. Assign paperRect and printableRect

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8) // A4, 72 dpi
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // 4. Create PDF context and draw

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect.zero, nil)



    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // 5. Save PDF file

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    print(documentsPath)
    //let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundlePath+"/PdfFiles/"

    pdfData.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/file3.pdf", atomically: true)

}
```

Comment: getting any solution @gajula

Comment: Were you able to resolve this!?

Answer (score -1):

Create the image url using `NSBundle` [URLForImageResource](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/bundle/1519886-urlforimageresource)...

```
let imageUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForImageResource("test")
```

Replace the image src in your hard-coded html with that...

```
let betterHtml = html.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("test.jpg", withString: imageUrl)
```

Comment: This didn't work for me... I used other approach instead of HTML. Thank you.

Comment: No worries. Post what you did to help others.